# Apollo Server 10x slower in lambda

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, apollo

I've setup an Apollo Server GraphQL API to get some data from a remote MongoDB database, hosted on Atlas. Now, if I run the server in localhost, using the server less framework, every request I made to the MongoDB server takes around 8-10ms, which is good. However, if I do the same request, to the same server, from a Lambda hosted on eu-west-1, that request takes around 90-130ms! And the worst part is that I need this Lambda to run on us-east-1, where there takes even longer (around 400ms!).

What could be the cause for this slowdown? I'm not talking about the first request, that takes over a second, but I guess is because of the Lambda starting...

I've set up a sample repository so you can see if this slowdown is related to some wrong configuration
https://github.com/GimignanoF/SampleApolloLambda

Comment: Is this every invocation? Could be round trip time. Where is the Apollo server?

Comment: Is in the index.js file :) I've lowered some times using DataLoader, but it still slower in Lambda than running locally using the same remote MongoDB server